# How to disable UIScrollView to a pan gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

How do I disable, or force to fail, the gesture recognizer in a `UIScrollView` when a pan gesture recognizer, lets call it `SomePanGestureRecognizer`, is called?

The `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldBeRequiredToFailBy:)` method takes a gesture recognizer parameter, not a pan gesture recognizer and I don't know if that's why I can't get it to work or because I'm making a syntax error.

I have `UIScrollView` subclassed and the method used to force fail is in the delegate below:

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        configure()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        configure()

    }

    private func configure() {

        isScrollEnabled = true
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        isPagingEnabled = true
        bounces = false
        alwaysBounceVertical = false
        alwaysBounceHorizontal = false

    }

}

// gesture recognizer delegate
extension CustomScrollView: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {   

    // allow simultaneous gestures
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // force failure
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        // TLDR: disable uiscrollview when SomePanGestureRecognizer is called

    }

}
```

And here is the pan gesture recognizer that needs to force the gesture recognizer in the `UIScrollView` to fail:

```
func addSomePanGestureRecognizer() {
    SomePanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(oneBPanGestureHandler(gesture:)))
    oneBHandle.addGestureRecognizer(SomePanGestureRecognizer)
}
```

**UPDATE** I subclassed the UIPanGestureRecognizer and got it to work using the simultaneous delegate but I fear that this is a shaky way to do it because I'm relying on UIKit to always disable the UIScrollView before the custom pan gesture.

```
// gesture recognizer delegate
extension CustomScrollView: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    // simultaneous gestures
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        if otherGestureRecognizer is CustomPanGestureRecognizer {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }

    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2** This also works but I don't know why because I feel like it shouldn't. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

```
// force failure
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

    if otherGestureRecognizer is CustomPanGestureRecognizer {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: `UIPanGestureRecognizers` is a subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` . That's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
   let isPanAndOtherRecognizer = gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer is SomePanGestureRecognizer
   return !isPanAndOtherRecognizer
}

// force failure
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

   let isPanAndOtherRecognizer = gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer is SomePanGestureRecognizer
   return isPanAndOtherRecognizer
}
```

Comment: Compile error: SomePanGestureRecognizer is an undeclared type

Comment: That's the class you specified. Use whatever your own subclass is.

Comment: I want the unnamed gesture recognizer in the UIScrollView to fail to the pan gesture recognizer SomePanGestureRecognizer. We must not be on the same page because this doesn't work.

Comment: I think the source of confusion here is that SomePanGestureRecognizer is an instance variable, not a class. I think PeejWeej might have seen it capitalized and thought it was a class.

Comment: I subclassed it and it still didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: As with most questions,the more common conventions you use and the more code you post, the easier it is diagnose your problem.

Comment: @GetSwifty I stumbled on to a huge subtle problem.  When you do this, it works perfectly. However. If the user begins a pan.  the pan *no longer reports* .changed, it reports nothing until .ended.  Thus, it's useless for panning!  It's a strange issue.